# simple mySQL error

Tags: java, mysql

Here is the overview of my database. I'm sure I am making a very simple mistake but I have tried removing specifying the location but that did not work.
It will only work if I change insertDataName to "grayson"

[image]

Here is the code I am trying to use

```
String insertDataName = "gray";
int insertDataValue = 1234;

int val = st.executeUpdate("INSERT into results (id, name ,value) VALUES (1, "+insertDataName+", "+insertDataValue+")");
```

Error I a'm getting
`Unknown column 'gray' in 'field list'`

That 'gray' is whatever I make insertDataName unless I make it 'grayson' then it doesn't enter anything into the name column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing enclosing quotes for `name` value

```
"INSERT into results (id, name ,value) VALUES (1, '"+insertDataName+"', "+insertDataValue+")");
```

Comment: thanks! i changed it to: int val = st.executeUpdate("INSERT into results (name ,value) VALUES (\""+insertDataName+"\", "+insertDataValue+")");

and it worked.. i removed id because it is auto incremented

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't directly inject values into a query, it's vulnerable to coding errors and from a security perspective. Look at PreparedStatement setString and setInt.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Answer (score 0):

Sure if you are using AUTO INCREMENT you don't have to specify the value for that field again.